# Manually installing a font map in TEXMFHOME - updmap can't find the map-file

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I am trying to install [newtx from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) for my user only. At first, I tried to follow the README which is available there.

First of, I am using `TeXlive 2011` on `Archlinux`. I have also checked if all my `TEXMF...` variables point to the right places using `kpsewhich --var-value`:

- `TEXMFHOME` = `/home/$USER/texmf`
- `TEXMFCONFIG` = `/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-config`

Then I did the "installation":

- `mkdir -p /home/$USER/texmf/tex/latex/newtx`
- `cp -r` everything from `newtx.zip` to that file
- Create the `ls-R` by running `texhash /home/$USER/texmf/`
- Run `updmap --enable Map=ntx.map`
- Get the first error:

`$ updmap --enable Map=ntx.map`:

```
copy /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg => /home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
Config file: "/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg"
dvips output dir: "/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfm output dir: "/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

/usr/bin/updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb
  prefer outlines                  : true
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 36 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  0 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [129 files]


ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    ntx.map

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can delete non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

It can't find `ntx.map`! I found this [guide for installing maps on Debian](http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/ch4.html), and tried to adapt it to my system. So I did the same steps as above, but now putting `ntx.map` into `/home/$USER/texmf/fonts/map/newtx/`.

`updmap --enable Map=ntx.map` runs through nicely now, and I can find an entry `Map ntx.map` in `/home/$USER/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg`, as it should.

But having a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \Phi(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^u_{-\infty} e^{-t^2/2} dt
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I get a compilation error with `pdflatex` now, it can't find the font `ntxmi` (just a small excerpt from the log):

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ntxmi
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map typeface abbreviation tx for ntxmi.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntxmi
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012/dev/Arch Linux)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ntxmi
! I can't find file `ntxmi'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntxmi

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntxmi

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ntxmi.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntxmi' failed to make ntxmi.tfm.
```

What to do?

**EDIT:** `kpsewhich newtxmath.sty` correctly points to `/home/$USER/texmf/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty`, and `kpsewhich ntx.map` to `/home/$USER/texmf/fonts/map/newtx/ntx.map`.

Comment: You probably have the `tfm` and `vf` files in the wrong place: they should go under `/home/$USER/texmf/fonts/tfm` and `/home/$USER/texmf/fonts/vf` respectively. However it's in general not a good idea to use `updmap` and install font packages in TEXMFHOME. Better use TEXMFLOCAL and `updmap-sys`, if you have administrator privileges.

Comment: @egreg: I guess the same applies to `.pfb` and `.fd` files? Also, I just realized: is the place for `ntx.map` correct, or do I need to place it into `TEXMFHOME/fonts/dvips/newtx` (or change dvips to pdftex or something like that alternatively)? You are right about TEXMFLOCAL; but since the TeXlive 2012 update is supposed to come soon, I just wanted to have this in my $HOME to get rid of it quickly.

Comment: `.fd` files should go in `.../tex/latex/newtx`. Note that `texhash` (or `mktexlsr` as it's called now) is *not* necessary for things in TEXMFHOME

Comment: Aha, we are getting somewhere! Thanks a lot; I had to also put the `.pfb` files into `TEXMFHOME/fonts/type1/newtx/`, and now everything compiles. I am happy! :-D

Comment: @egreg: Are you sure about not needing to run `texhash` on `TEXMFHOME`? If I do not do this, then `pdflatex` will not see `newtxmath.sty`. The same is true for any other package installed in `TEXMFHOME` (for example, I also have the developmental version of `PGF` in there). Without `texhash` and the proper `ls-R` in `TEXMFHOME`, `pdflatex` will always use `TEXMFDIST` (`/usr/share/texmf-dst/`).

Comment: When you do `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMF`, the `/home/$USER/texmf` subpath should not be preceded by `!!`, like, for instance, `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist`. If this is the case, remove the `ls-R` file and never force `mktexlsr` on TEXMFHOME.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't copy all the content of your zip into `tex/latex/`. The various file types must go in different branches of your local texmf tree. E.g. the `.tfm` should go in `/fonts/tfm/newtx`,  the `.vf` in `fonts/vf/newtx` and so on. Look in your main texmf tree for examples of correct pathes.

Comment: see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation

Answer (score 6):

You cannot simply copy everything into the latex directory, as mentioned above. The files should be placed in the following directories:

- *.enc -> fonts/enc/public/newtx/
- *.map -> fonts/map/dvips/public/newtx/
- *.tfm -> fonts/tfm/public/newtx/
- *.pfb -> fonts/type1/public/newtx/
- *.vf -> fonts/vf/public/newtx/
- *.fd, *.sty -> tex/latex/newtx/

If you put them in $HOME/texmf ($TEXMFHOME) then no need to run mktexlsr (or texhash, which is the same).

After that re-run the updmap call as you did.

Comment: From those of us stuck behind proxy's and firewalls that block the auto installer I thank you. All I wanted was a List of locations and Files for those places and here it is.