# newtxmath and can't find file 'zxxrl7z'

Tags: fonts, errors, mactex

I use BasicTeX on OS X 10.9 Mavericks (for space problems on a Macbook Air). I usually manage to find the packages that I miss by interpreting `pdflatex`-errors, but this time I cannot find a clue to what package I miss.

I tried using

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

but I get the following error message:

```
! I can't find file `zxxrl7z'.
```

Of course the package `newtx` is installed. Could someone tell me which package `zxxrl7z` belongs to?

Comment: Please, take a look at http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/ctan/fonts/boondox/fonts/tfm/public/boondox/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60539/manually-installing-a-font-map-in-texmfhome-updmap-cant-find-the-map-file?rq=1

Comment: `boondox` was exactly the package I needed! Thanks! You can write an answer and I will flag it. Can I also ask you how you found the package based on the file name, so that I can use the same method in the future? Did you locate it in your distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the package `boondox` through Google (searching for `zxxrl7z`).

Also, I used the Unix command `find`:

`MacAir-Papiro $ sudo find /usr/local/texlive/ -name 'zxxrl7z.*'
/usr/local/texlive//2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/boondox/zxxrl7z.tfm`

to locate the file in the file system.